# Find the maximum value of the integral $\int_{-1}^1|x-a|e^xdx$ where $|a|\le1$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

**Question:**

Find the maximum value of the integral $\int_{-1}^1|x-a|e^xdx$ where $|a|\le1$

**My Attempt:**

Let $f(a)=\int_{-1}^a(a-x)e^xdx+\int_{a}^1(x-a)e^xdx$

$f'(a)=\int_{-1}^ae^xdx+\int_{a}^1-e^xdx$

$f'(a)=e^a-e^{-1}-(e-e^a)$

For maximum, $f'(a)=0$

So, $2e^a-e-e^{-1}=0\implies 2e^a=e+\frac1e$

So, $e^a=\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\implies a=\ln\left(\frac{e^2+1}{2e}\right)$

But the answer given is: Max value $e+e^{-1}$ when $a=-1$

What's wrong in my approach?

**Edit:**

For derivative, I have used [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: Shouldn't $f'(a)$ be just $e^a - (-e^a)$?

Comment: I disagree with your differentiation. You could be right, but, it’s not justified. One must be careful when the bounds and the integrand are both variable

Comment: @lisyarus I think my derivative is correct. I have edited my post. Please have a look.

Comment: @FShrike I have edited my post. Are we still in disagreement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from your step: $f'(a)=e^a-e^{-1}-(e-e^a)$

$$f''(a)=2e^a>0$$

So your $a=\ln(\frac{e^2+1}{2e})$ is local minima, not maxima, the function is concave up with respect to $a$, so you will find the maxima at one of two endpoints. Therefore, it is consistent with the answer in your book, which occurs at $a=-1$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome @aarbee